# Android opengles stuttering scrolling

Tags: android, optimization, opengl-es

I've created a small simple world that is 480x320.
I have just implemented smooth scrolling but one problem I keep noticing is that it stutters slightly a few times.
I think I have know why it's stuttering but fail to realize how exactly to fix my problem.
I am NOT using the delta time in my scrolling calculations as it only confuses me even more.
How is the delta value supposed to be used?
I am usually getting a value like .2something as my delta time.
I have also set the FPS limit to 30FPS (33 to be exact) and the frame rate has NEVER gone below 30 in all my tests.
My solution to scrolling is increasing the xPos value by the TILE_SIZE (32) and comparing the camera.x value to xPos and increasing or decreasing camera.x by a certain amount (4).
Now I'm not sure how to use the delta in this example.
I have tried:
SPEED * deltaTime = definitely not right;
SPEED * (1 + deltaTime) = not right;
SPEED +/- deltaTime = more stuttering;

Am I correct in thinking not using the delta time is causing the stuttering and if so can someone help me?
Or is this a different matter altogether?

Comment: I assume all your calculations are in float or double right?

Comment: correct. well actually just floats

Comment: So your DELTA time should average around 0.03f assuming 33FPS. If we assume your game scrolls UNIT(10) per second we would then calculate the current position by using POSITION = POSITION + UNIT * DELTA... does this help? I do not completely understand what the xPos and camera.x are in your case.

Comment: The xPos and camera.a are used for my method of scrolling the camera/viewport. I'm going to test it out right now.

Comment: Just keep in mind that you don't increase by 32 or by 4 you increase by delta * 32 and delta * 4 if 32 and 4 are your units of movement per second. Then you should be fine.

Comment: This is exactly where I am getting stuck. If I want to move in the LEFT direction, I increase the position of my camera (The character is always in the middle and I move the background/camera) by 4pixel units which I'm assuming takes 8FPS to get to my goal position of: 32. When ever I multiply the delta with 4 I get a very small number so instead of moving 4pixels, I'm moving 4 * 0.03f which is not what I want. I'm sorry I still don't get it.

Comment: You want the camera to move 32px in 8fps. You have an average of 33fps. That means it takes 0.24s to move 32px which comes down to 133.3px movement per second. So the movement unit you want to multiply with delta is 133.3 not 4. Makes sense? Try to think in terms of time not in frames.

Comment: Makes sense, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You should use a fixed time step approach, that would ensure more consistent results.

If you haven't read the now quite famous, "[Fix your Timestep](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)!" article, I would recommend you to do so.

Cheers!